# How to make my page aware of a button that didn't exist on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have an `.aspx` page and a separate `.js` file that contains all of my `JavaScript` and `jQuery`. The page also has a `UserControl` that doesn't exist on page load and that only appears when a certain button is clicked. And the `UserControl` contains, among other things, a `JavaScript` button.

The problem I'm having is connecting the newly-created `JavaScript` button that didn't exist on page load to my `.js` file.

At first I tried adding a `jQuery` select to get the button that lives inside the `UserControl` to the `document.ready()` that's in my existing `.js` file like this:

`$(".TheClassOnMyUserControlButton").click(function () {
    // do stuff here
}`

But I couldn't get it to respond to anything I tried. So I put my `jQuery` inside a `<script>` tag in the `UserControl` page itself and the button suddenly started responding.

I have since come to understand that the reason the `jQuery` select wasn't working from the `.js` file is because the button didn't exist on page load and you can't select a thing that doesn't exist, and that makes sense now.

So my pseudo-newbie developer brain started trying to figure out how I could refresh the `document.ready()` in my `.js` file once the `UserControl` was on the page so that it would become aware of the newly-created `UserControl` and its buttons.

I asked another developer that I work with about it and they said to try bind.jquery without explaining how.

Googling that led me here as usual and I saw in the `jQuery` documentation that their `bind()` method has been deprecated and they suggest using `on()` instead.

I think I understand what the other developer meant and I know what I *want* to do, but I'm getting a little fuzzy on the details and I'm not exactly sure how to use `on()` to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I know I could just leave the `<script>` tag inside the `UserControl`, but I'd like to keep all my `JavaScript` and `jQuery` in one place if I can.

Does anyone have any suggestions or things I could try?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I'm sorry, another developer I work with came and helped me with this and basically gutted everything I was trying to do with jQuery event delegation and the on() method, so this question doesn't even apply anymore. I appreciate the efforts of those that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to bind an event to a button.

1.) simply write a function and bind it to the button on the event you want. For example:

```
<script>function doStuff(){
    ....
    }
</script>
<button onclick="doStuff()">Do Something</button>
```

2.) You have to bind your function at the moment you have created the button. For example:

```
$('#Container').append('.button');
$('.button').on('event',doStuff);
```

For a more in depth answer i have to see your code

Answer (score 0):

You can bind jQuery methods or events using the "on" method by looking at the entire document and then in the "on" method specifying the correct selector. Hope that makes sense. You can check the example below.

```
$(document).on("click", ".className", function (){ /*code here*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the button beforehand and hide it. Then, show that button/section/panel on the event of other actions.

```
C# code behind
control.Visible = false;
control.Visible = true;

or

Jquery/bootstrap front end
$('#myElementID').addClass('hidden');
$('#myElementID').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: This is a plausible solution, but the whole reason I created a User Control in the first place was to keep everything it contains from the initial page load and make it so they can see that bit if they want to after the fact.